# Pyinstaller y su incompatibilidad con scipy - statsmodel

Tags: pyinstaller, scipy

Hace algún tiempo inicié con un proyecto donde necesito crear un ejecutable y encontré que pyinstaller es de las mejores funciones para crear ejecutables. Ejecuto el comando con pyinstaller en cmd y enseguida ejecuto el .exe generado y siempre me sale un error de name: 'obj' is not defined. Ya he investigado mucho y no he podido solucionar el problema. Si alguien tiene conocimiento o les ha pasado algo similar les agradezco un consejo.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.